# QT: QLabels not respecting borders

Tags: c++, qt5

I'm creating a very basic QT Application and I'm running into the following problem:

```
rasp4home::ui::MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    paletteSetup();

    mTime.setText("00.22");
    mTime2.setText("00.21232");

    setLayout(new QBoxLayout(QBoxLayout::TopToBottom));

    layout()->addWidget(&mTime);
    layout()->addWidget(&mTime2);
}

void rasp4home::ui::MainWindow::paletteSetup()
{
    setAutoFillBackground(true);
    auto palette = QApplication::palette();
    palette.setColor(QPalette::All, QPalette::Background, backgroundColor);
    palette.setColor(QPalette::All, QPalette::WindowText, textColor);

    setPalette(palette);
}
```

Now I would expect both labels to show up ordered top to bottom but I'm getting them on top of each other. What am I doing  wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a widget *inside* the main window and set it as the `centralWidget`, and set your layout in this widget.

Note: this example was done on macOS, and so it doesn't have the same namespace.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
        paletteSetup();

        mTime.setText("00.22");
        mTime2.setText("00.21232");

        QBoxLayout* layout = new QBoxLayout(QBoxLayout::TopToBottom);

        layout->addWidget(&mTime);
        layout->addWidget(&mTime2);

        QWidget* mainWidget = new QWidget();

        mainWidget->setLayout(layout);

        // QMainWindow will free mainWidget when appropriate
        setCentralWidget(mainWidget);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh thank you. I didn't know QMainWindow needed that.